# Set initial value to datablock column in runtime

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

How set initial value to column in data block from database, when F6 key (new row) is pressed and clear this value if new row enter is cancelled?

Combobox have WHEN-LIST-CHANGED trigger:

```
declare
where_param varchar2(250);
begin
    :LOCAL.CUR_CUSNUM := :LOCAL.ORG_LIST;
    if :LOCAL.CUR_CUSNUM is not null then
        :LOCAL.WHERE_STRING := 'CUSNUM = ' || :LOCAL.CUR_CUSNUM;
    else
        :LOCAL.WHERE_STRING := '1=1';
    end if;
    Set_Block_Property('MC_ZVP_PL_TRUSTED_PEOPLE_CORP', DEFAULT_WHERE, :LOCAL.WHERE_STRING);
    Go_Block('MC_ZVP_PL_TRUSTED_PEOPLE_CORP');
    --Clear_Block('MC_ZVP_PL_TRUSTED_PEOPLE_CORP');
    Execute_Query; 
end;
```

I need to set initial value depending on the selected element in combobox or kind of something to insert row with value from combobox hidden from user.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WHEN-CREATE-RECORD trigger on MC_ZVP_PL_TRUSTED_PEOPLE_CORP block